# Does a monopoly in a commodity in Sheriff of Nottingham gain both bonuses?

Tags: scoring, sheriff-of-nottingham

In the end-game scoring of Sheriff of Nottingham the majority holder of each legal commodity gets a bonus, as does the 2nd-majority holder.

If one play happens to be the only trader of a commodity do they get both bonuses or just the 1st-majority one?  Not covered by the rules.

Comment: I am not sure but I think that it is a sign of very bad play if only 1 person decides to play a certain good as if you can get the 2nd tier bonus with only one good that will be a good bonus. I would think they only get the king bonus based on the splitting in ties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got a canonical answer elsewhere from Tony Gullotti, Sales Director at the publishers (Arcane Wonders).  You only get the King bonus.  To quote:

"You have the most chickens, so you get the King's Bonus. There is no second most, so no Queen's Bonus is awarded."

Comment: Is it possible to add a quote from his response to your answer? That would certainly answer the question that was asked. And then you can accept your own answer if you'd like, since it'd have more support than mine.

Comment: Added as requested.

Answer (score 4):

As per [the rules](http://files.geekdo.com/geekfile_download.php?filetype=application%2Fpdf&filename=SoN_Rulebook_CH09_singlepages.pdf&filecode=pw4u6leh9p&validationcode=237bdbfd598c06866f36aa27b4ac1450) (may need a BoardGameGeek.com account to access):

> The player who has successfully delivered the *most* and the *second most* of each type of **Legal** Good is declared the “King” and “Queen”, respectively, of that Good.

I would interpret this to mean each player can either be the King or Queen (or split the points in a tie), but not both. Hence, even a monopoly on a Good would only net the King's bonus.

If the single commodity holder got both the King and Queen bonuses, you could also make the following argument: when there isn't a monopoly, the player with the highest number of goods also always ties for the second highest number of goods. That player would always get the King's points and some portion of the Queen's. This doesn't seem like a logical interpretation of the rules, and most people with the second most number of Goods would be pretty annoyed if this were happening. If a player only gets a single bonus when there isn't a monopoly, the same rule should apply unless otherwise stated by the rulebook, which in this case it isn't.

Comment: There _are_ a number of games where there are 1st and 2nd majority bonuses and, if there's no 2nd, the 1st player gets both.  That probably seeded our confusion over this point.